# scrollTo horizontal scrolling a little rough - jQuery

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have used the scrollTo plug-in on the following site http://normli.ca/new to achieve a single page horizontal scrolling site. For the most part it works great and scrolls smoothly but seems to be a bit rough when scrolling to the "liquid" page. Is there any way to make it scroll smoothly? Below is a snippet of the code I have used.

jQuery(document).ready( function(){

```
// easing function
$.easing.elasout = function(x, t, b, c, d) {
    var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
    if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
    if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
    else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
    return a*Math.pow(2,-10*t) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p ) + c + b;
};

//resets the page
$('body').scrollTo( 0 );
$.scrollTo( 0 );

    //click function
$('.three').click(function(){
    $('#back').hide();
    $('#container').fadeOut('slow');
    $.scrollTo(5695, 1500, {axis:'x', easing:'easeInOutExpo'}); 
});
```

});